# asp HyperLinkField - need to show text

Tags: asp.net

I have the following HyperLinkField:

```
     <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="SysID" DataNavigateUrlFields="SysID"  
      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="pgmtasklist.aspx?sysid={0}"  Text="Click Here" />
```

I need the hyperlink text to say Click Here but not working as expected. It shows the actual SysID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the DataTextField definition and it should work:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="SysID"  
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="pgmtasklist.aspx?sysid={0}" Text="Click Here" />
```

Since you have DataTextField it's expecting a `DataTextFormatString` value as well, but in your case you don't need either.